# Restarting toilet line after 50 years

Tags: plumbing, water, toilet, sewer

I have a sewer opening in my basement for a toilet. The flange looks just fine, but that sewer line has probably not been used in 50 years.

Is there anything I should do before starting to use it? Or just pour some water down it and see what happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make someone happy and have it video inspected and/or snaked (where "someone" is the guy who gets paid) but there's plenty of 100 year old waste plumbing still in service, and not being used does not harm the pipe. Dump 5 gallons down there and see if it leaves promptly - if not, **then** spend extra money on it.

Comment: +1 on dumping water down it to see what happens. If the flange was cover/sealed well, nothing should have stopped it up....